# Eloquent save method not working when the data comes from Vue frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, axios

I have this code in a Vue Component:

```
           sendUserData(){
                axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
                        data: {
                            id: this.id,
                            name: this.name,
                            email: this.email,
                            password: this.password
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                        }
                    }
                ).then(response => {
                    if(response.data == 'success'){
                        this.$emit('userSaveSuccess')
                    } else {
                        this.$emit('userSaveError')
                    }
                });
            }
```

and I have this in a Laravel Controller:

```
public function saveUser($name = '', $email = '', $password = ''){

    $id = request('data.id', 0);
    $name = request('data.name', $name);
    $email = request('data.email', $email);
    $password = request('data.pswrd', $password);

    Log::info(request());

    if($id == 0){
        $saveUser = new User;
    } else {
        $saveUser = User::find($id);
        if($name == ''){
            $name = $saveUser -> name;
        }
        if($email == ''){
            $email = $saveUser -> email;
        }
    }
    $saveUser -> name = $name;
    $saveUser -> email = $email;
    if($password != ''){
        $saveUser -> password = bcrypt($password);
    }
    if($saveUser->save()){
        return 'success';
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

My problem is, that it's `output` is success, but in the MySQL DB nothing has changed.
In the Log's I got this:

> [2019-09-08 12:32:08] local.INFO: array (
>    'data' => 
>    array (
>      'id' => 2,
>      'name' => 'AdminTest',
>      'email' => 'admin@test.com',
>    ),
>   )

(The original name is Admin -> the Laravel function got the request)

I tested it with Postman, too, and that time the save method worked.

What's the problem?

**Edit:**
Images

[image: Console]
[image: Postman]

**Edit2:**

`console.log(response)` image

[image: console.log(response)]

Comment: You can shorten your code and eliminate some ifs if you use updateOrCreate() method.

Comment: Tried `updateOrCreate()` and mass assignment, too, but the same problem also was here

Comment: can you show me what you send with postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Replace your saveUser() method with the following and it will work.

```
/**
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function saveUser(Request $request){

    // validate request data
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'pswrd' => 'required' // add your custom validation rule
    ]);

    // throw an validation error with message
    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json(['message' => 'The given data was invalid.', 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);

    // best way to get request input values ( laravel docs )
    $id = $request->get('id') ?? 0;
    $name = $request->name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->psswrd;

    // TODO: you can replace the logic with ( updateOrCreate($saveUser) )
    if($id == 0){
        $saveUser = new User;
    } else {
        $saveUser = User::find($id);
    }

    $saveUser -> name = $name;
    $saveUser -> email = $email;

    if($password != ''){
        $saveUser -> password = bcrypt($password);
    }

    try{
        $saveUser->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Success.', 'data' => $saveUser], 200);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error.', 'data' => $exception->getMessage()], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: But bare in mind he is sending a data object with params inside.

Comment: that's ok . check validation message

Comment: I didn't got any validation message just a 422 error in console

Comment: check  this line (// add your custom validation rule ) for password name

Comment: I add by mistake ( password ) but it should be ( pswrd ) like your input name .

Comment: In Postman it's working, but in the app I still got 422 error

Comment: Do this without outer {} ```axios.post('/api/saveUser', { name: ... }```

Comment: update the question with an image of postman and console please that's will help to debug the issue

Comment: @AhmadElkenany I added the images. Also I deleted the `data: {}` outer layer from axios but also without success

Comment: Can you add this line at the first of method body for debugging? ( return $request->all(); )

And clean your request url (localhost: 8000/api/saveUser)

Comment: @AhmadElkenany I added it as Edit2

Comment: In Postman the result is : `{"id": "2","name": "Admin","email": "admin@myemail.com"}`

Comment: what is the request body you send throw ( axios.post )

Comment: axios.post('/api/saveUser', {
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name,
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                        }
                    }
                )

Comment: Is password input  missing from the request  ?

Comment: I disabled to be required at the moment, becouse not that the problem